# SQL MIN() with GROUP BY select additional columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to query a sql database table for the minimum price for products. I also want to grab an additional column with the value of the row with the minimum price. My data looks something like this.

```
ProductId | Price | Location
1         | 50    | florida
1         | 55    | texas
1         | 53    | california
2         | 65    | florida
2         | 64    | texas
2         | 60    | new york
```

I can query the minimum price for a product with this query

```
select ProductId, Min(Price)
from Table
group by ProductId
```

What I want to do is also include the Location where the Min price is being queried from in the above query. Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Comment: And what do you want to have happen if multiple locations have the same `min(price)`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.productid = t.productid);
```

In most databases, this has very good performance with an index on `(productid, price)`.